# CKEditor Character Count

Tags: javascript, jquery, count, ckeditor, character

First of all, this question WAS answered here: [CKeditor character/word count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1651389/ckeditor-character-word-count) but all the answers give broken links... therefore it's not answered.

Using CKEditor, how to I get the character count on keyup, using jquery?

Here's what ***should*** work, but does ***not*** work:

```
<textarea id="newKnowledge_body"></textarea>
<script>
 $(function(){
      // this DOES work, fyi
      $("#newKnowledge_body").ckeditor();

      // this DOES NOT work
      $("#newKnowledge_body").keyup(function(){
          var len = $("#newKnowledge_body").val().length;
          alert(len);
      });
 });
</script>
```

I believe the problem lies in the "keyup" event.  I don't get any response when referring to it like that... but I don't know what else to use.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a quick solution with no plugins (not the best)

```
var len = $("#cke_contents_message").children("iframe").contents().find("body").text().length;
```

[UPDATE] THE BETTER WAY TO DO THAT

```
var editor = $('YOUR_TEXT_AREA').ckeditorGet();
editor.on("instanceReady", function(){                    
    this.document.on("keyup", function(){
        var editorContent = $(editor.getData());
        var plainEditorContent = editorContent.text().trim();
        console.log(plainEditorContent);
        console.log("Length: "+plainEditorContent.length);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to register an event on the CKEditr like so:

```
editor.on( 'key', function( evt ){
   updateCount( evt.editor.getData() );       
}, editor.element.$ );
```

I also found this link that has a nice character count using jQuery and css.
http://jsfiddle.net/VagrantRadio/2Jzpr/

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.change()` instead of `.keyup()`